# Two Polytropic and Two Adiabtic processes in Thermodynamic cycle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, reversibility, heat-engine

$1$ mole of an Ideal gas performs a reversible cycle with 2 adiabatic and 2 polytropic processes.

$A(P_0,V_0,T_0)$ to $B$ with $V_B=V_A/\lambda$ with an adiabatic process.

$B$ to $C$ with a polytropic process where $P=C_1V^{1/2}$

$C$ to $D$ with an adiabatic process.

$D$ to $A$ with a polytropic process where $P=C_2V^{1/2}$

Find the cycles efficiency and draw the PV diagramm of the cycle.

Solution:

Since there is heat exchange only during the two polytropic processes we can easily calculate the efficiency to be $η=1-\frac{Q_{out}}{Q_{in}}=1-\frac{T_C-T_B}{T_A-T_D}$ since we know $C_{23}=C_{41}=C$ since the processes share the same $k=-\frac{1}{2}$.

$T_B=1.6T_A$ can easily be calculated using the fact that AB is adiabatic and PV=RT.

My problem is that I can find no way to calculate sates C and D. This is because i have only 3 equations to calculate $(PC,Vc,Pd,Vd)$. These equations are:

$P_C=C_1V_C^{1/2}$

$P_D=C_2V_D^{1/2}$

$P_C V_C^{γ}=P_D V_D^{\gamma}.$

So the two polytropic processes could end anywhere and $T_C$,$T_D$ cannot be determined. Same goes for the Pressure and Volume at those points. What I am saying is that in this $P-V$ diagramm the red line could be moved anywhere to the left or to the right and where exactly it is affects the efficiency of the cycle.

[image: P-V diagramm of cycle.]

I tried using the fact that $\Delta U=0$ for the whole cycle but it didnt get me anywhere.
Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: You said that the location of CD can be slid to the left or the right, and this will affect the calculated efficiency.  But, if this is solved correctly, you will find that that is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input data don't seem to be consistent.  For the adiabatic leg from A to B, we must have $$\frac{P_B}{P_A}=\left(\frac{V_A}{V_B}\right)^{\gamma}=6.4086$$From the polytropic equations, we must have $$P_A=13V_A^{1/2}$$and$$P_B=42V_B^{1/2}$$implying that $$\frac{P_B}{P_A}=\frac{42}{13}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{1/2}=1.615$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I double checked the problem and made sure that I copied everything exactly as it is written. You seem to be right, there must be an error in the data. By the way, I read your previous answer and used the fact that the change in entropy for the full cycle must be 0 to prove that T4/T1=T3/T2 which gives me the efficiency of the engine easily.Now I know how to approach these kind of situations. Im not gonna bother with the rest of the problem since it probably doesn't make a lot of sense. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of the problem that is consistent.  Maybe you would consider solving this one?

Let $\lambda = V_A/V_B$, and let the polytropic relationships be given by:

$P=C_1V^{1/2}$ for D to A

$P=C_2V^{1/2}$ for B to C

1. In terms of $\lambda$ and $\gamma$, for a consistent formulation, what is the ratio $C_2/C_1$?
2. Show that $\frac{V_D}{V_C}=\frac{V_A}{V_B}$, and thus that $\frac{V_D}{V_A}=\frac{V_C}{V_B}=r$
3. Derive an expression for the efficiency of the cycle exclusively in terms of $\lambda$ and $\gamma$

Comment: Thank you! I edited the original question so people will see the corrected version instead. Considering that the entropy over the whole cycle is 0 seems to be the key for this problem. One question still holds though: Is it possible to figure out exactly what the C and D points are? The original problem asks for the P-V diagramm to be drawn. This still doesn't seem to be possible unless we do it in terms of r.

Answer (score 0):

This is a homework and exercise problem and the rules are solutions should not be given. I haven't attempted to follow your analysis, but here is some general guidance that may be of help.

Both the reversible polytropic and reversible adiabatic process for an ideal gas has the
form

$$PV^{n}=C$$

where $C$ = constant.

For the adiabatic process,

$$n=\frac{C_{P}}{C_{V}}$$

Which equals 1.34 for the adiabatic processes, per your information.

I suggest you combine these equations with the ideal gas equation which, for one mole of gas, is

$$PV=RT$$

Which applies to the equilibrium states A, B, C and D, and you may be able to determine the properties at states C and D.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry but if you haven't even read my thoughts on the problem how are you supposed to help me? I'm aware this question falls into this category but it should also be obvious that my question definitely isn't of the type "please solve this for me". Answering this question will help me ,and maybe others as well ,get a better understanding on the physics behind this "homework"

Comment: I am only asking you if have combined the ideal gas equation with the  equations for the polytropic adiabatic processes. Often times folks don’t. If you did, great.

Comment: In short, did you consider using the ideal gas law as your fourth equation? That is 

$$\frac {P_{C}V_C}{T_C}=\frac{P_{D}V_D}{T_D}$$

Comment: I tried it but it adds two extra unknown variables. Now we get a system of four equations with six unknown variables